# ¿Como hacer una consulta que busque los resultados que no contengan una palabra?

Tags: php, eloquent

Como hacer una consulta que busque los resultados que no contengan una palabra? 
por ejemplo la siguiente consulta me busca en la base de datos las tablas que en el campo numero sea igual a la variable y lo que necesito es lo contrario que busque las tablas que el campo numero sea diferente a la variable.

```
mails = Mail::where('numero', '$variable')->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el `whereNotIn` significa `donde no está`:

```
mails = Mail::whereNotIn('numero', '$variable')->get();
```